# ArrayList add() method not working. Can't add another value and add it to jTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have a problem with my code. I am currently making a project to store temporary data on ArrayList. I've already created the code, but when I test it, it seems that the add() method from `ArrayList` is not working.
I show the `ArrayList` on `jTable`, but it always returns empty, even though the `add()` method gives success notification.

I've read about another solution here, but no one that fits my problem.
Here is my code. I have 3 Class

**Input.java**

```
package latihan;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author anang
 */
public class Input extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Latihan latihan = new Latihan();
    /**
     * Creates new form Input
     */
    public Input() {
        initComponents();
    }                      

    private void btnKirimActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String nik = txtNIK.getText();
        String lap = txtLaporan.getText();

        try {
            latihan.addLaporan(nik,lap);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Berhasil");
            Tabel t = new Tabel();
            t.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }

    }                                        
    public ArrayList<String[]> getLaporan(){
        ArrayList<String[]> arr = latihan.getLaporan();
        return arr;
    }                 
}
```

The second Class
**Latihan.java**

```
package latihan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Latihan {
    private ArrayList<String[]> lap = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getLaporan(){
        return this.lap;
    }

    public void addLaporan(String Nik, String Lap){
        String[] data = new String[]{Nik,Lap};
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data yang diinputkan = "+Nik+" "+Lap, "Latihan.java",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        this.lap.add(data);
    }

}
```

The third class
**Tabel.java**

```
package latihan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author anang
 */
public class Tabel extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    //Input i = new Input();
    private Input input;
    public Tabel() {
        initComponents();
        addDataToTable();
    }                       

    private void btnTambahActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:        
        input.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);

    }                                         

    public void addDataToTable(){
        DefaultTableModel tbModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        tbModel.setRowCount(0);
        ArrayList<String[]> arr = input.getLaporan();

        Object rowData[] = new Object[2];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Jumlah data : "+arr.size());
        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,arr.get(0)[0]);
            rowData[0] = arr.get(i)[0];
            rowData[1] = arr.get(i)[1];
            tbModel.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }                
}
```

What is wrong with my code?? Can somebody help me??

Thank you

Comment: When you say " I show the `ArrayList` on `jTable`, but it always returns empty" are you referring to `addDataToTable` in your `Tabel` class not updating `JOptionPane` with the options from the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Ambro-r, when I get arr.size() in `Table` class, it always returns 0, even after the addLaporan() method in `Latihan` class

Comment: You problem has to do with your stack and how you calling classes. See my extend answer below.

Comment: The problem is your design. Get rid of the ArrayList. Just add the data directly to the TableModel. The TableModel is the data structure for the storage of your data. There is no need to store the data in two places.

Comment: @camickr This is an assignment from my lecturer, we are assigned to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason your `JOptionPane` is not being updated with values from your `ArrayList` is because your `ArrayList` is empty. The `add()` method works fine, it's your implementation that is incorrect.

In `addDataToTable()` when you call `ArrayList<String[]> arr = input.getLaporan();` it will go fetch the `ArrayList` stored in your `Input` class instance for that instance of `Tabel` (...spelling...). This instance of `Input` that you are calling is a completely different instance for the one you created your `Tabel` instance from, because in your `Tabel` class you instantiated a new `Input`. Hence the `ArrayList` that you are retrieving is going to be blank because no-where in the instance of `Tabel` have run any code the invokes the add method.

Confused? Essentially it's a problem to do with your stack and how you calling classes:

To try show how the variables from the same class can be different based on instances, you can run the following example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyListClass {

  private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  private static ArrayList<String> staticList = new ArrayList<>();

  public MyListClass(int instance) {
    for(int i = 0; i < instance; i++) {
        list.add(instance + ":" +i);
        staticList.add(instance + ":" +i);
    }
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getList() {
    return list;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getStaticListList() {
    return staticList;
  }

}

public class MyInstanceClass {

  private int instance;
  private MyListClass listClass;

  public MyInstanceClass(int instance) {
    this.instance = instance;
    listClass = new MyListClass(instance);
  }

  public void showMeWhatYourListLooksLike() {
    System.out.println(String.format("For instance %d, the list has the following info: %s", instance, listClass.getList().toString()));
  }

  public void showMeWhatYourStaticListLooksLike() {
    System.out.println(String.format("For instance %d, the STATIC list has the following info: %s", instance, listClass.getStaticListList().toString()));
  }


  public void createAnotherInstance() {
    MyInstanceClass anotherInstance = new MyInstanceClass(30);
    anotherInstance.showMeWhatYourListLooksLike();
  }

}

public class MyMainClass {

  public static void main(String...args) {
    MyInstanceClass myInstanceClass01 = new MyInstanceClass(1);
    MyInstanceClass myInstanceClass05 = new MyInstanceClass(5);
    MyInstanceClass myInstanceClass10 = new MyInstanceClass(10);

    myInstanceClass01.showMeWhatYourListLooksLike();
    myInstanceClass05.showMeWhatYourListLooksLike();
    myInstanceClass10.showMeWhatYourListLooksLike();

    myInstanceClass01.showMeWhatYourStaticListLooksLike();
    myInstanceClass05.showMeWhatYourStaticListLooksLike();
    myInstanceClass10.showMeWhatYourStaticListLooksLike();

    myInstanceClass10.createAnotherInstance();
  }

}
```

... notice that for each instance, of `MyInstanceClass` the list being printed out when you call `showMeWhatYourListLooksLike()` is different, however the list being printed out when calling `showMeWhatYourStaticListLooksLike()` is the same. That is because the `static` list is shared across all instances `MyListClass` (think about it this way... when something is `static` there can be only one).

... you'll also notice what happens you create another instance of `MyInstanceClass` inside `myInstanceClass10`.

So to solve your immediate issue. Instead of creating a new `Input` object in `Tabel`, just pass your `Latihan` object when you instantiate `Tabel` and call the list directly from that object.

```
public class Input extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  Latihan latihan = new Latihan();

  public Input() {
     initComponents();
   }                      

  private void btnKirimActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      ...
      try {
        ...
        Tabel t = new Tabel(latihan);
        ...
      } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
      }
  }                                        

}

public class Tabel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public Tabel(Latihan latihan) {
    ...
    addDataToTable(latihan);
  }    

  public void addDataToTable(Latihan latihan){
    ...
    ArrayList<String[]> arr = latihan.getLaporan();
    ...
  }                
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry not include this code, but there is a problem on the jframe open if the Tabel's constructor is set like that.

`public static void main(String args[]){
              java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(newRunnable(){
                        public void run() {
                               newTabel().setVisible(true);
                        }
               });
}`

Comment: What should i do with that problem?

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN, where is this code running? It's not in your question. I'm also not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That code running In Tabel class. Tabel is a JFrame Form in NetBeans

Comment: Here is the full project on NetBeans https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IPt-Q8chsgCoi5928WEZtV_-1ALo--mI/view?usp=sharing .. I'll be very Happy if you would like to help me.. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, finally i got it. I have to modify my code to use your method. And it's work.

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN, sorry for only getting back now, been a bit busy. Glad you got it working! Well done!